# Undertanding the fourier trasform of $(1+\vert x\vert^4)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The function
$\varphi(x)=(1+\vert x\vert^4)^{-1},$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^d, d<4,$ is a good example of a function that is not the Schwartz space but it has a defined Fourier transform.

It satisfies that
$$\varphi(x)\leq C(1+\vert x\vert)^{-(d+\delta)}, \delta=4-d. $$

I'm trying to proof or disproof that its Fourier transform has a similar property, ie I would like to know if there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$\hat\varphi(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\varphi(x)d\xi\leq C(1+\vert \xi\vert)^{-(d+\delta)}.  $$

I have the impression that the proof is not hard but I'm not an expert in Fourier analysis and I have no idea about where to start.

Comment: It's not in the Schwartz space, but it is a [tempered distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform). That's why it has a defined Fourier transform.

Comment: Here's a hint: play around with integration by parts.

Comment: Since the function is smooth, you should get a nice decay of the Fourier transform (decaying faster than any polynomial) which can be proved by integrating by parts several times. The fact that it only decays like $1/x^4$ for large $x$ will only change the local regularity of the Fourier transform.

Comment: You use both the symbol phi and f. Is this a typo or it is not stated precisely what you are looking for?